# Perl interpret regex from text file

Tags: regex, perl

I'm a beginner in Perl and I have a question about regex.
The aim of the script I'm working on is to substitute a string by another in an XML file. These strings are on a text file, that looks like this :

```
mot-clé, mot clé
noeud, nœud
version (\d), version&#8201;(\d)
Codename One, Codename&#8201;One
```

The script takes each lines of this file and put them in a hash table, and then the key is substitute by its value :

```
# Open file text and recupration of the lines in a table @t
%hach = @t;
foreach my $k (keys(%hach)) {
   s/$k/$hach{$k}/sg;
}
```

Substitutions are made on an XML file. For example, before I run the script, it looks like this :

```
<title>Codename One</title>
<para>Le mot-clé de la version 3 .....</para>
<para> .... noeud .... </para>
```

I'd like it to looks like this after passing the script :

```
<title>Codename&#8201;One</title>
<para> Le mot clé de la version&#8201;3 .....</para>
<para> .... nœud .... </para>
```

For the moment, the substitution is done for "normal" strings but not for the strings that contain regex. For these strings, I woud like perl to interpret characters related to regex as well. Then, the script will be able to make all substitutions.
Here is my question: is it possible for Perl to interpret these strings as regex ? And if it's possible, how?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Anything is possible, if you build it. You will need to show us your code, your real input (or an example that resembles there real data) and your expected output for us to help you. Please also see [ask] and [mcve]. (I take it you are not talking about parsing the XML using regular expression, right? You want to use things from an XML file to substitute text in a flat file.)

Comment: @simbabque:  *"You want to use things from an XML file to substitute text in a flat file"* I think the opposite: the substitutions are in the text file and are applied to XML files.

Comment: Well simple search/replace in an XML that only touches text, but not structure, is fair game in my book @Borodin. :)

Comment: Have you tried that? It should already do what you want. The default behaviour is to treat variables like patterns when they are interpolated into a `m//` or `s///` on the left-hand-side. You'd have to specifically `quotemeta` them or wrap them in `m/\Q$pattern\E/` to disable that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make a distinction between text keys and regex keys in the code. For regex keys, use double-eval substitution and also *backreferences* in the corresponding values if there are capture groups.

```
use 5.026;
use Tie::RefHash;
use strictures;

my %subst;
tie %subst, 'Tie::RefHash';
%subst = (
    'mot-clé' => 'mot clé',
    noeud => 'nœud',
    qr'version (\d)' => 'version&#8201;$1',
    'Codename One' => 'Codename&#8201;One',
);

my $text = <<'';
<title>Codename One</title>
<para>Le mot-clé de la version 3 .....</para>
<para> .... noeud .... </para>

foreach my $k (keys %subst) {
    if (ref $k eq ref qr'') {
        $text =~ s/$k/qq("$subst{$k}")/eegms;
    } else {
        $text =~ s/$k/$subst{$k}/gms;
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't think that using a heredoc that's terminated by an empty string is a little obscure for code that's aimed at a beginner?

Comment: @DaveCross I didn't even know that was possible. :D

Comment: @simbabque: Neither did I, but I was trying to sound cool :-)

Comment: Nah, it's fine.